# How can I reference an ID for patch request when using useFormState in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In NextJS 14, I'm using `useFormState` to handle a form that allows users to update a user's profile. However, my endpoint is `PATCH /user/:userId` and there doesn't seem to be a way to provide my server action with the `userId`. One ideaI add was to add a form field which had the user's ID as the value but was set to both disabled and invisible (using Bootstrap), but that doesn't seem great:

```
<div className="col-6 invisible">
   <input
      type="text"
      className=""
      id="name"
      name="name"
      disabled={true}
      value={params.userId} />
</div>
```

This would then be provided to my server action like so:

```
const [ state, formAction ] = useFormState(updateUser, null);
```

This doesn't seem ideal as I might not want to expose internal IDs. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a viable solution online. Perhaps I'm going about it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass additional arguments to a Server Action using the JavaScript bind method. See [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#passing-additional-arguments)
So you could do something like..

```
const updateUserWithId = updateUser.bind(null, user.id)
const [state, formAction] = useFormState<State, FormData>(updateUserWithId, null);
```

What I need is to validate the form in the server action and then work work out the changed values, so I also bind the initial values and do this after validation.